# IntelliJ for Android and C code development

Tags: android, c, android-studio, intellij-idea, clion

I was using clion to develop a c library which is going pretty well. Clion is a pretty nice ide.

Recently I started doing more android development and I use the ndk with my clion project to build my android applications using the jni interface.

With android studio they use build.gradle which I am starting to prefer over cmake and since my custom c library isn't very large at the moment it would be fairly trivial to move the entire project over to gradle. Here's the rub though, I can't seem to find a way to create a c project in android studio and I would prefer to avoid going from clion to android studio and back again. They are both intellj products. I wouldn't mind migrating my c library project to a gradle build system if that would allow me to work with one ide and avoid the switching back and fourth.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to find a way to create a c project in android studio

Because *Android Studio* is a project which was made by Google based on the *Intellij Idea Community Edition* sources. Google has no intention to support the Java projects or C projects in their IDE simply because they are making IDE for Android development.

If you want to keep all your projects in one IDE you can switch to Intellij Idea and install [C/C++](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373?pr=) plugin. This approach has some drawbacks:

1. Mentioned C/C++ plugin is made by some third-party vendor, not the JetBrains team, and, I suppose, supports less features compared to CLion.
2. The Android support is better in Android Studio.

Personally, I'd prefer to use both Android Studio and CLion - it isn't too much of a hassle for me after all.